# CRTP - Is it possible to make an abstract base class?

Tags: c++, abstract-class, crtp, static-polymorphism

I'm implementing a static polymorphism:

```
template<typename T>
class Base {
public:
    void method() {
         // do something
         impl();
         // do something else
    }
    void impl() { // intended to be private
        static_cast<T*>(this)->impl();
    }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived> {
public:
     void impl() { // intended to be private
     }
};
```

This code is a static implementation of a dynamic polymorphic classes where `void impl()` was pure virtual. So the base class was abstract.

Now these classes implement static polymorphism and therefore don't have pure virtual functions.

Is it possible to make Base class abstract, so that objects of this class can't be created?

Comment: You can make the constructor of `Base` protected, which will prevent the creation of a `Base` object. However, I'd strongly recommend looking at using the polymorphism  features already built into the language even though there is a slight bit of addition overhead incurred from the `vptr` as such overhead is unlikely to make much difference in the overall performance of the program

Answer (score 2):

You can use a protected destructor and constructors:

```
template<typename T>
class Base {
public:
    void method() {
         // do something
         impl();
         // do something else
    }
    void impl() { // intended to be private
        static_cast<T*>(this)->impl();
    }

protected:
    Base() = default;
    ~Base() = default;

    // If you don't want to implement proper copying/moving:
    // Base(const Base&) = delete;
    // Base(Base&&) = delete;
    // Base& operator=(const Base&) = delete;
    // Base& operator=(Base&&) = delete;
};
```

This will even disallow a derived class's member functions to create base class objects, as well as trying to delete a pointer whose static type is `Base<T>`.

Comment: I think you need all 5 special members protected to prevent it as reliably as a true abstract class.

Comment: @StoryTeller, I admit I'm not too knowledgeable in this area. I couldn't find a difference, but I'd love to know.

Comment: I'm thinking `new base(derived)`, and co. This avoids the d'tor. Granted, I'm a bit Machiavellian here, but an abstract base won't let it fly.

Comment: new Base<Derived>(); creates object in dynamic memory

Comment: @StoryTeller, Hmm, that's a good point. And I can see your point of all special members following from that, though it would be possible to implement copying and moving appropriately.

Comment: @beginpluses, It certainly shouldn't pass if the default constructor is protected. I figured that case was covered *enough* by the destructor before, but it really would be best to include everything.